# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin for admin panel. Just change association in Image model

From this

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user 
   belongs_to :product 
end
```

to this

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :user 
   has_one :product 
end
```

and User model is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :images,dependent: :destroy
end
```

Getting this error when I try to edit user from admin panel.From other side it is working fine.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /user/72/edit

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.image_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."image_id" = $1...
                                         ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."image_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has great documentation. The documentation for `has_one` [found here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) states that "This method should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key" so it is looking for the foreign key of `image_id` on the `user` record. You would create this through a migration; please see this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22815259/2578505) for more information on foreign keys and migrations.

But before you go that far, please consider:

- Why would you change the Image relation from `belongs_to :user` to `has_one :user` in the
  first place? To boil down SQL associations and how Rails maps to them, if user `has_many :images` then images must necessarily
  `belong_to` user; they are opposite sides of the relation, with an
  exception being a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation. If A belongs to B, then B has one (or many) of A. I would strongly encourage you to keep the images as having `belongs_to` relationships, while User and Product can `have_many` images. To anecdotally explain why this makes sense: a user might have profile pictures of their face, their house, etc. (`has_many :images`). A product (shoes) might have multiple pictures of the same shoe (`has_many :images`), but it is very unlikely that a particular picture of a shoe would map to both a user and a product.
- I would strongly encourage you manage images and attachments using a gem like [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) or [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). If you're handling uploaded file attachments, libraries like this will save you headaches down the road when it comes to resizing, image compression, etc. I am sure your direction in trying to change the relation was informed by some of the issues that these gems will solve for you.

Comment: I understand your explanation but I am using a single image table for both user and product . User image is saved at the time of new_user and edit_user and same as for product. user can have maximum 3 images. user and product have no direct relation it is like this user->store->products .But when I am using belongs_to for both user and product their ids is required in image table that's not I want. if user save a image than in image table product_id is null and vice versa and this is not happening in case of belongs_to .

Comment: That makes sense and one image table is good design; in this case you may need to have an intersection table the columns "entity, entity_id, image_id" Entity would be the class name and the id, so a row would be something like "User, 1, 2" where 1 is the user_id and 2 is the image_id. I again encourage you to use something like Attachinary, which handles all of this setup for you.

Comment: One more note on that is that the "has_many" would also need a "through:" declaration. More information on that here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I am using paperclip for image uploading and I updated my previous comment.

Comment: Awesome! This guide covers how to use paperclip for this well: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start
So to speak practically, User and Product would both have ` has_attached_file :image` and you should be set

Comment: I hoped this helped as my main goal was to provide a quick answer after your initial post; if it didn't hopefully other answers can help.

Comment: Just a little rails 5 trick
`class Image < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :product, optional: true

end`

It is working for me and thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

**Check capitalization**

I arrived here because I was using incorrect capitalization in the column name.

The column was `advertiserName`, and I was doing

```
Listing.where(AdvertiserName: "Lowes")
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column listings.AdvertiserName does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."Advert...
```

Changing the query to `Listing.where(advertiserName: "Lowes")` fixed it immediately.

**Check quotes**

[Note also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14987636/5783745) that PostgreSQL is not forgiving when using double quotes in

**Check capitalization in column names**

See more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156175/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgundefinedcolumn-error-column-does-not-exis?noredirect=1#comment122229040_69156175)