# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column does not exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm running a simple query:

```
Listing.where('advertiserName LIKE ?', '%lowes%')
```

and I get the following error

```
Listing.where('advertiserName LIKE ?', '%lowes%')
D, [2021-09-13T00:26:42.656409 #4] DEBUG -- :   Listing Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (advertiserName LIKE '%lowes%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "advertisername" does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (advertiserName LI...
                                                   ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "listings.advertiserName".
```

#### 4 attempts to solve

**1**

I double checked the column name exists:

```
Listing.column_names
=> ["id", "language", "jobId", "jobTitle", "jobClassification", "jobSubClassification", "advertiserName", "advertiserId",
```

**2**

I made sure I was [using single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14987636/5783745) like PostgreSQL requires.

**3**

I ran a similar query on another table in the same app, and it seems to work just fine:

```
Metric.where('average_salary_by_language LIKE ?', '%Hadoop%')
# returns results
```

**4**

I did as suggested in the error message, and tried replacing `advertiserName` with `listings.advertiserName`:

```
Listing.where('listings.advertiserName LIKE ?', '%lowes%')
D, [2021-09-13T00:31:36.017492 #4] DEBUG -- :   Listing Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (listings.advertiserName LIKE '%lowes%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column listings.advertisername does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (listings.advertis...
                                                   ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "listings.advertiserName".
```

#### Other ideas

I can see the error message says:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column listings.advertisername does not exist

I know that `advertisername` doesn't exist - it's clearly `advertiserName` (with a capital 'N'), and that's what I'm using. Could rails/AR/postgres have a bug?

Comment: Not a bug, but that doesn't mean it works as you are clearly expecting, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253713/camelcase-column-in-postgresql-database-in-rails-activerecord#answer-45256592

Comment: @RockwellRice you nailed it. Note to self: ***never*** use camel case in db column names. This works `Listing.where('"advertiserName" LIKE ?', '%lowes%')` (single quotes because [postgres requires single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987634/rails-and-heroku-pgerror-column-does-not-exist-for-where-argument/14987636#14987636), and double quotes around the column containing camel case because [object names are case-insensitive in ANSI/postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253713/camelcase-column-in-postgresql-database-in-rails-activerecord#answer-45256592))

Comment: Have you tried `Listing.arel_table[:advertiserName].matches(Arel::Nodes.build_quoted("%lowes%"))` Not a huge fan of using String SQL and this should avoid that "requirement"

Comment: @engineersmnky I gave it a try, but I can't seem to get any records as results, just some info like this: `=> #<Arel::Nodes::Sum:0x0000556181bf5da0 @expressions=[#<Arel::Nodes::Matches:0x0000556181d63728 @left=#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#<Arel::Table:0x0000556180bed318 @name="listings", @type_caster=#<ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Map:0x0000556180bed368 @types=Listing(id: integer, language: string, jobId: integer, jobTitle: string,` (it goes on much more). Is there something I'm missing that should be done after executing the Arel to ensure it returns the results?

Comment: @stevec I am not sure where that result is coming from. You should just be able to replace your where condition e.g. `Listing.where(Listing.arel_table[:advertiserName].matches(Arel::Nodes.build_quoted("%lowes%")))`

Comment: Hi @max I wondered if you would consider reopening. The reason being, the duplicate has the same *solution*, **and** the same *cause* (excellent grounds for it being a duplicate), however, it has a different *symptom*! I realise that's a fine point of difference, but leaving this question open will allow someone experiencing this particular symptom (`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:`) to work through possible causes and find the solution more quickly.

Comment: From [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/are-questions-with-different-symptoms-same-cause-same-solution-duplicates#comment868256_411592): it is indeed considered a duplicate (I retracted my reopen vote).